# Does "xsl:apply-templates mode"Copy" copy the whole node, or just the data?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have the following XSLT element:

```
<xsl:template match="Product">
    <product>
        ...
        <xsl:if test="string-length(PerProductShipping) > 0">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="PerProductShipping" mode="Copy">
                <xsl:with-param name="name">per_product_shipping</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
    </product>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="Copy">
    <xsl:param name="name" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This is my current output:

```
<per_product_shipping>8.79</per_product_shipping>
```

This is my desired output:

```
<per_product_shipping is_absolute="true">8.79</per_product_shipping>
```

The `is_absolute="true"` element will be hard coded, and always present.

How can I add an attribute to this `xsl:template`?

Comment: How should we know?  You haven't shown us the `xsl:template`.

Comment: That is the only "template" defined in the code.  That is, I don't have a separate template defined anywhere.

Comment: Where are the `<xsl:template>` tags?  What's the output you're currently getting?

Comment: @JLRishe I have no `<xsl:template>` tags other than what you see here.  My current output is what you see above, `<per_product_shipping>8.79</per_product_shipping>`

Comment: Could you provide your entire XSLT?  Or are those five lines the whole thing?

Comment: @JLRishe my entire XSLT is 600 lines long, and has proprietary information in it.  Let me add a bit more.

Comment: Your XSLT is 600 lines long and yet it only has one "template" and no `<xsl:template>` tags (for the record, there are 0 `<xsl:template>` tags in the XSL you've posted here)?

Comment: @JLRishe no, it has many templates, but none corresponding to this element.  Would you mind moving this to chat?

Comment: Thanks for adding the template tags.  It looks like your `<xsl:apply-templates>` is calling a template that has the mode "Copy" (i.e. a different template from this one).  Could you provide that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22605/discussion-between-pheonixblade9-and-jlrishe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in chat, your mode="Copy" template is a general-purpose template that creates an element with the name specified in the parameter, and then gives it same text value as the node being matched.  I believe the most advisable solution in this case would be to replace this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="PerProductShipping" mode="Copy">
    <xsl:with-param name="name">per_product_shipping</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

with this:

```
<per_product_shipping is_absolute="true">
  <xsl:value-of select="PerProductShipping" />
</per_product_shipping>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend this approach:

```
<xsl:element name="per_product_shipping"> 
<xsl:attribute name="is_absolute">true</xsl:attribute> 
<xsl:value-of select="..." /> 
</xsl:element>
```

This way you have dynamic control over the produced XML.